# separate row containing two separate dates into before and after midnight

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a data frame containing sleep data, with several sleep increments, with a column for the start and a column for the end of the sleep.
For some rows, the starting time is on the previous day and the end time is on the next day.
What I would like to do is to separate such rows into two rows, where the first row contains the starting time till 23:59:59, and the second row 00:00:00 till the end time.

For example:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  sleepdatestarttime  sleepdateendtime    sleepstage 
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>              
1 2018-03-02 23:31:00 2018-03-02 23:54:00 rem                
2 2018-03-02 23:54:00 2018-03-02 23:55:00 light              
3 2018-03-02 23:55:00 2018-03-03 00:02:00 wake               
4 2018-03-03 00:02:00 2018-03-03 00:03:30 light              
5 2018-03-03 00:03:30 2018-03-03 00:23:30 deep               
6 2018-03-03 00:23:30 2018-03-03 02:58:00 light
```

and the desired output is:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  sleepdatestarttime  sleepdateendtime    sleepstage 
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>      
1 2018-03-02 23:31:00 2018-03-02 23:54:00 rem         
2 2018-03-02 23:54:00 2018-03-02 23:55:00 light       
**3 2018-03-02 23:55:00 2018-03-02 23:59:59 wake 
4 2018-03-03 00:00:00 2018-03-03 00:01:59 wake** 
5 2018-03-03 00:02:00 2018-03-03 00:03:30 light       
6 2018-03-03 00:03:30 2018-03-03 00:23:30 deep        
7 2018-03-03 00:23:30 2018-03-03 02:58:00 light
```

A `dplyr` solution would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution but using just base R and not a dplyr.  I converted all times to UTC to avoid issue with time conversions.  (See a related answer [change time zone in R without it returning to original time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506071/change-time-zone-in-r-without-it-returning-to-original-time-zone#comment91952977_52506071))

Note this solution resorts the entire dataframe by sleepdatestarttime so if there are multiple people on the same day, then the order function on the last line needs modification.

```
df<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="sleepdatestarttime  sleepdateendtime    sleepstage 
'2018-03-02 23:31:00' '2018-03-02 23:54:00' rem                
'2018-03-02 23:54:00' '2018-03-02 23:55:00' light              
'2018-03-02 23:55:00' '2018-03-03 00:02:00' wake               
'2018-03-03 00:02:00' '2018-03-03 00:03:30' light              
'2018-03-03 00:03:30' '2018-03-03 00:23:30' deep               
'2018-03-03 00:23:30' '2018-03-03 02:58:00' light")

df$sleepdatestarttime<-as.POSIXct(as.character(df$sleepdatestarttime), tz="UTC")
df$sleepdateendtime<-as.POSIXct(as.character(df$sleepdateendtime), tz="UTC")

    #find rows across days
rows<-which(as.Date(df$sleepdatestarttime) !=as.Date(df$sleepdateendtime))

#create the new rows
nstart<-data.frame(sleepdatestarttime= df$sleepdatestarttime[rows], 
                   sleepdateendtime= as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(df$sleepdatestarttime[rows]), "23:59:59"), tz="UTC"),
                   sleepstage=df$sleepstage[rows])

nend<-data.frame(sleepdatestarttime= as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(df$sleepdateendtime[rows]), "00:00:00"), tz="UTC"), 
                 sleepdateendtime= df$sleepdateendtime[rows],
                 sleepstage=df$sleepstage[rows])

#substitute in the new start rows
df[rows,]<-nstart
#tack on the new ending rows
df<-rbind(df, nend)
#resort the dataframe
df<-df[order(df$sleepdatestarttime ),]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue in genomics. The [`IRanges`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html)  package on BioConductor has the `findOverlaps()` function for this purpose. `foverlaps()` is its [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) version which is used here. AFAIK, there is no [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) equivalent available.

First we need to create a vector of day start and end times. The call to `foverlaps()` returns all possible types of overlaps. Finally, the start and end times are adjusted to match with the expected result.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
day_seq <- setDT(df)[, .(day_start = seq(
  floor_date(min(sleepdatestarttime), "day"), 
  ceiling_date(max(sleepdateendtime), "day"), "day"))][
    , day_end := day_start + days(1)]
setkey(day_seq, day_start, day_end)

foverlaps(
  df, day_seq, by.x = c("sleepdatestarttime", "sleepdateendtime"), nomatch = 0L)[
    , `:=`(sleepdatestarttime = pmax(sleepdatestarttime, day_start),
           sleepdateendtime   = pmin(sleepdateendtime, day_end - seconds(1)))][
             , c("day_start", "day_end") := NULL][]
```

> ```
>    i  sleepdatestarttime    sleepdateendtime sleepstage
> 1: 1 2018-03-02 23:31:00 2018-03-02 23:54:00        rem
> 2: 2 2018-03-02 23:54:00 2018-03-02 23:55:00      light
> 3: 3 2018-03-02 23:55:00 2018-03-02 23:59:59       wake
> 4: 3 2018-03-03 00:00:00 2018-03-03 00:02:00       wake
> 5: 4 2018-03-03 00:02:00 2018-03-03 00:03:30      light
> 6: 5 2018-03-03 00:03:30 2018-03-03 00:23:30       deep
> 7: 6 2018-03-03 00:23:30 2018-03-03 02:58:00      light
> ```

#### Data

```
df <- readr::read_table("i  sleepdatestarttime  sleepdateendtime    sleepstage 
1 2018-03-02 23:31:00 2018-03-02 23:54:00 rem                
2 2018-03-02 23:54:00 2018-03-02 23:55:00 light              
3 2018-03-02 23:55:00 2018-03-03 00:02:00 wake               
4 2018-03-03 00:02:00 2018-03-03 00:03:30 light              
5 2018-03-03 00:03:30 2018-03-03 00:23:30 deep               
6 2018-03-03 00:23:30 2018-03-03 02:58:00 light")
```